# How to pass a delegate^ to a native class in c++/cli

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-cli

I have a native class

```
public NativeClass:
{
public:
    typedef void(*Func)(cv::UMat image);

    void setFunc(Func func);
}
```

and would like to pass a function as parameter from managed class.

```
ref ManagedClass:
{
    public:
        ManagedClass()
        {
           NativeClass* nativeClass = new NativeClass();
           nativeClass.setFunc(doSomething);
        }


    private:
        doSomething(cv::UMat image)
        {
            //do something
        }
}
```

But it seems to not work. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Before you pass the delegate as a function pointer, you need to create a delegate first.

In C#, you just need to reference the method name without parenthesis. In C++/CLI, you need to explicitly call the delegate constructor, and you need to pass explicit parameters of the object to call the method on, and the method in a C++-style.

```
MyDelegate^ del = gcnew MyDelegate(this, &ManagedClass::doSomething);
// Explicit ctor  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// Pass the object to be called on ^^^^
// Pass the method in the C++ style      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Once you have that, you can just pass the delegate to the method that takes a raw function pointer. It knows how to convert the managed delegate object to a function pointer. There's a good example in [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-define-and-use-delegates-cpp-cli?view=vs-2015#pass-a-delegate-to-a-native-function-that-expects-a-function-pointer). You *must* be sure to keep around the managed delegate object **forever**. As soon as the managed delegate is garbage collected, the raw function pointer stops working.

Once you have that, you'll need to look at your parameter type, `cv::UMat`. I don't know what type that is or where you're getting it, but you may need to adjust your parameter type on the managed side, the unmanaged side, or both. (This is why I didn't declare the delegate type in my example above; I wasn't sure what would work so I left it generic. If everything works, then you might be able to use `Action<cv::UMat>` as your delegate type.)

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I wrote the following code 
`delegate void MyDelegate(cv::UMat image);`
`MyDelegate^ d = gcnew MyDelegate(this, &ManagedClass::doSomething);`
`nativeClass->setFunc(d);`
But it output a error **E0167 argument of type "ManagedClass::MyDelegate ^" is incompatible with parameter of type "NativeClass::Func"** in the `setFunc(d);` line.
I also try to delete the `cv::UMat`parameter in the `Func` and and `MyDelegate`. But it shill output this error. Do you have any idea? Thanks.